# Force DNS Redirect in AWS VPC for Public Hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc, kops

I am trying to deploy a kubernetes cluster into an AWS environment which does not support Route53 queries from the generated hostname ($HostA). This environment requires an override of the Endpoint configuration to resolve all Route53 queries to $HostB. Note that I am in not control of either host, and they are both reachable on the public internet. The protokube docker image I am deploying is not aware of this; to make it aware, I would need to build the image and host it myself, something I do not wish to do if I can avoid it (as I would probably have to do this for every docker image I am deploying).

I am looking for a way to redirect all requests to $HostA without having to change any docker configuration. Ideally, I would like a way to override all requests to $HostA from within my VPC to go to $HostB. If this is not possible, I am in control of the EC2 userdata which starts up the EC2 instances which hosts the images. Thus, perhaps there is a way I can set /etc/host.alises in the EC2 host and force this to be used for all running containers (instead of the container's /etc/host). Again, please keep in mind that I need to be able to control this from the host instance and NOT by overriding the docker image's configuration.

Thank you!

Comment: If you're using .2 then you can use Route53 incoming/outgoing rules. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver-forwarding-inbound-queries.html

Comment: I am indeed using .2. This looks to be the opposite of what I need, but perhaps the Outbound resolver will work. Basically, all queries from my VPC (which will go to .2) to the public internet for $HostA need to be redirected to $HostB on the public internet. Note that I a not in control of either host.